# gulp browsersync sass partials

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync, gulp-sass, gulp-browser-sync

I have the following problem and don't know whats going wrong with my gulpfile. Everything is working fine and my sass files are being compiled and the browser refreshed when changing something.
But if I add a new partial file and import it into my _base.scss, browsersync is only recognizing the change in that partial and is not compiling the whole sass file & reloading the browser. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I could not figure out a good solution. 
Thanks!

Here's my gulpfile.js

```
  /*=============================================>>>>>
= gulpfile - all the gulptasks are here =
===============================================>>>>>*/



/*----------- variables -----------*/

// gulp
var gulp          = require('gulp');
// css stuff
var postcss       = require('gulp-postcss');
var sass          = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer  = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var cssnext       = require('postcss-cssnext');
var lost          = require('lost');
var csswring      = require('csswring');

// javascript
var babel         = require('gulp-babel');

// jade
var jade          = require('gulp-jade-php');

// browser sync
var browserSync   = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload        = browserSync.reload;


/*----------- tasks -----------*/

// style task
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer,
    cssnext,
    lost,
    csswring
  ];

  return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
    ;
});

// javascript task
gulp.task('javascript', function(){
  return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/dist/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});


// jade task
gulp.task('jade', function(){
  return gulp.src('./jade/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./templates/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});


// browser sync
gulp.task('browserSync', function(){
    var files = [
      './scss/**/*.scss',
      './css/style.css',
      './*.php',
      './templates/**/*.php',
      './js/*js',
      './jade/*jade'
    ];
    browserSync.init(
      files, {
      proxy : 'localhost:8888/jobs/heisaplan/',
    });
});

// watching the files for changes
gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['javascript']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./jade/**/*.jade', ['jade']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./templates/**/*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// default gulp task
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'browserSync', 'styles', 'javascript', 'jade']);
```

Comment: hi,Are you sure that the wather sees the changes to the new partial? Cause gulp watch doesn't consider new files at least that's what I know

Comment: thanks for your reply! hm.. how can i make sure that gulp watch is able to detect new files? Is there any workaround for this?
Thanks! :)